# I am struggling to pass { user } prompt between components

Tags: reactjs, firebase

In my Fire.jsx - which has all my firebase data and I am treating sort of like the model
I have...

```
//Fire.jsx
export const userData = await setDoc(doc(db, "users", { user }), {
  email: user
});
```

Problem:  I keep getting user not defined

What I want to happen: I want to pass the user variable (which right now is an email)
to the second category of the users collection, so the user data is stored in the email.
I am trying to store user data.

I am importing { user } from my Dashboard.jsx like this

```
//Dashboard.jsx
export default function Dashboard({ setUser, setAuthState, user }) {
  console.log(user);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <Nav />
      <div className="main">
        <MenuPopupState setUser={setUser} setAuthState={setAuthState} />
      </div>
      <Fire user={user} />
      <Temp user={user} />
      <Typography color="textSecondary" align="right" variant="h6">
        logged in as {user}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the user variable is being into Dashboard.jsx from my App.jsx component

App.jsx

I know that the data is passing correctly because when I console.log(user) upon the state switching to dashboard - i get the current logged in email. So the data is passing to the dashboard correctly from the App, but for some reason not to Fire from Dashboard

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(null);
  const [authState, setAuthState] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unSubscribeAuth = onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      async (authenticatedUser) => {
        if (authenticatedUser) {
          setUser(authenticatedUser.email);
          setAuthState("dashboard");
          // console.log(authenticatedUser);
        } else {
          setUser(null);
          setAuthState("signin");
        }
      }
    );
    return unSubscribeAuth;
  }, [user]);

  if (authState === null) return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  if (authState === "register")
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <Register setAuthState={setAuthState} setUser={setUser} />
      </div>
    );
  if (authState === "signin")
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav />
        <SignIn setAuthState={setAuthState} setUser={setUser} />
      </div>
    );
  if (user)
    return (
      <Dashboard setAuthState={setAuthState} setUser={setUser} user={user} />
    );
  return (
    <div>
      <Register />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

https://scrimba.com/scrim/czKKzWSM

I've attached a scrim for clarity